# types to model different events in typescript

Tags: typescript

Say I have the following three objects:

```
{
  id: 1,
  time: 1000,
  type: 'A',
  data: { a: 'one' }
}

{
  id: 2,
  time: 1001,
  type: 'B',
  data: { b: 123 }
}

{
  id: 3,
  time: 1002,
  type: 'C',
  data: { c: 'three', d: 123 }
}
```

and I want a function along the lines of

```
function buildEvent<TData,TEvent>(id: number, time: number, TData data): TEvent {}
```

What would my types look like so that I can implement `buildEvent`? It looks like there's a bit of intersection, a bit of union, and a bit of generic.

So for example, say I have something like:

```
type DataA = {a: string}
type DataB = {b: number}
type DataC = {c: string, d: number}
type EventHeader = {id: number, time: number}
type EventA = EventHeader & { tag: 'A', data: DataA}
type EventB = EventHeader & { tag: 'B', data: DataB}
type EventC = EventHeader & { tag: 'C', data: DataC}
type Event = EventA | EventB | EventC
function buildEvent<T extends Event, U extends DataA|DataB|DataC>(
  id: number, time: number, data: U): Event
{
  return {
    id: id
    time: time
    type: 'something in here?'
    data: data
  }
}
```

I feel I'm getting confused here in here union types should be used and how I might generally use generic types.

Many thanks!

Comment: It is really not clear what you are asking here. You have a generic method signature. You could name TData and TEvent whatever you want, like T and E. You can pass every type to them. What you maybe want is to restrict the passable types? Then the `extends` keyword should help you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The question is not fully clear. But from your objects and the function I was able to assume your need, hopefully correctly.

The issue which I had was that `buildEvent` had not `type` argument which was visible in all objects. That way I needed to change this as type is `discriminant` for our union. It means that it indicates which data we should use.

Take a look on fallowing solution:

```
// data + type
type TDataA = { type: 'A', data: { a: string } };
type TDataB = { type: 'B', data: { b: number } };
type TDataC = { type: 'C', data: { c: string, d: number } };

type TData = TDataA | TDataB | TDataC
type TBase = {
    id: number,
    time: number
}
type TEvent = TBase & TData; // our event is a product of Base and Type+Data

// pay attention data argument was changed into typeAndData
function buildEvent<T extends TData>(id: TBase['id'], time: TBase['time'], typeAndData: T): TBase & T {
    return {
        id,
        time,
        ...typeAndData
    }
}

const eventA = buildEvent(1, 1000, { type: 'A', data: { a: 'a' } }); // correct
eventA.data.a // properly has only a

const eventAWrong = buildEvent(1, 1000, { type: 'A', data: { b: 'a' } }); // error - wrong data

const eventB = buildEvent(1, 1000, { type: 'B', data: { b: 11 } }); // correct
```

Last thing, as you see I did not use really `TEvent` type in `buildEvent`, but type which is returned by `buildEvent` can be assigned to `TEvent` as it match structurally. Here is a prove:

```
type BuildEventIsTEvent = ReturnType<typeof buildEvent> extends TEvent ? true : false;
// above evaluates to true
```

Comment: perfect! I see exactly now the fault in my thinking. many thanks